# Is a QGraphicsSceneEvent::widget() always a QGraphicsView?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

According to [the docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicssceneevent.html), `QGraphicsSceneEvent::widget()` returns a QWidget. Isn't the widget *always* going to be a QGraphicsView, though (or null)?

I would assume so, except then I don't understand why the devs wouldn't have just made it `QGraphicsSceneEvent::view()`.

The reason I'm asking is that in my subclassed QGraphicsScene, I have overridden `QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent()` and I want to know which view originated the event--I'm wondering if it's safe to static cast `widget()` to a QGraphicsView, or if it's conceivable that some other widget could have created the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, `QGraphicsSceneEvent::widget()` returns the viewport widget, not the QGraphicsView. If you want the QGraphicsView, you would need to use: `event->widget()->parent()`.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation page you refered mentions the `QGraphicsView` as a target of events:

> When a QGraphicsView receives Qt mouse, keyboard, and drag and drop
>   events (QMouseEvent, QKeyEvent, QDragEvent, etc.), it translates them
>   into instances of QGraphicsSceneEvent subclasses and forwards them to
>   the QGraphicsScene it displays. The scene then forwards the events to
>   the relevant items.

However, if you doubt that `QGraphicsSceneEvent::widget()` always returns `QGraphicsView`, or you relay that it should always be a `QGraphicsView` you can check that by using `qobject_cast`:

```
QGraphicsView *view = qobject_cast<QGraphicsView *>(event->widget();
if (view) {
    // Handle the event
} else {
    // This is something that I do not expect.
    // ..
}
```

Comment: Your answer led me to figure out the right answer. Thanks.